# Gdalserver purpose and function

Tags: gdal, references

What does gdalserver do and how does it work?

I can't seem to find the documentation explaining how to use it.

Comment: https://helpmanual.io/help/gdalserver/

Answer (score 5):

Gdalserver creates a proxy for running some processes in isolated space. It is perhaps best documented in https://www.osgeo.cn/gdal/doxygen/gdal_api_proxy.html.

> When dealing with some file formats, particularly the drivers relying
> on third-party (potentially closed-source) libraries, it is difficult
> to ensure that those third-party libraries will be robust to
> hostile/corrupted datasource.
>
> The implemented solution is to have a (private) API_PROXY driver that
> will expose a GDALClientDataset object, which will forward all the
> GDAL API calls to another process ("server"), where the real driver
> will be effectively run. This way, if the server aborts due to a fatal
> error, the calling process will be unaffected and will report a clean
> error instead of aborting itself.

and later:

> For now, the server launched is the gdalserver executable on Windows.
> On Unix, the default behaviour is to just fork() the current process.
> It is also possible to launch the gdalserver executable by forcing
> GDAL_API_PROXY_SERVER=YES. The full filename of the gdalserver
> executable can also be specified in the GDAL_API_PROXY_SERVER.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping it was a way to process data on a remote machine.. It seems this isn't the case.

I'm not sure why it has port options if it wasn't intended for this purpose